# One javascript prompt overwrites the other prompt and i have to click submit twice to send the form

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a form which will (a) prompt user to fill in the missing fields and (b) prompt user to check at least one checkbox. But somehow the prompt `textbox.setCustomValidity('Choose at least one.');` is always overwritten by `e.target.setCustomValidity("Fill in the missing field");`.

And there is one more problem in Chromium. It looks like I have to click Submit button twice to be able to submit...

```js
//Function that checks if any input text field is empty and prompts user
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
            for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                elements[i].oninvalid = function(e) {
                    e.target.setCustomValidity("");
                    if (!e.target.validity.valid) {
                        e.target.setCustomValidity("Fill in the missing field");
                    }
                };
                elements[i].oninput = function(e) {
                    e.target.setCustomValidity("");
                };
            }
});


//Functions which checks if at least one checkbox is checked and prompts user to check at least one
function chooseKrozek() {
            if (document.querySelectorAll('input[name="krozek"]:checked').length > 0){
                document.querySelector("#krozki-checkbox-placeholder").value = document.querySelector('input[name="krozek"]:checked').value;
            }
            else {
                document.querySelector("#krozki-checkbox-placeholder").value = "";
            }
}   

function promptIzberiKrozek(textbox) {
            if (textbox.value == ''){
                textbox.setCustomValidity('Choose at least one.');
            }
            else {
                textbox.setCustomValidity('');
            }
}
```

```html
<form target="_blank">

name:<br>
<input class="vnos" type="text" name="ime" value="" required><br>
surname:<br>
<input class="vnos" type="text" name="priimek" value="" required>

<br><br>

checkboxes:<br>
<!-- placeholder to be able to display the prompt on invalid value -->
<input id="krozki-checkbox-placeholder" type="text" value="" oninvalid="promptIzberiKrozek()" required style="width:5px;height:5px;opacity:0;position:absolute;"/>
                    
<!-- On checkbox click function chooseKrozek() is called -->
<input type="checkbox" name="krozek" onClick="chooseKrozek()" value="linux-c-arm">LINUX/C/ARM™
<input type="checkbox" name="krozek" onClick="chooseKrozek()" value="linux-desktop">LINUX/DESKTOP™
<input type="checkbox" name="krozek" onClick="chooseKrozek()" value="linux-office">LINUX/OFFICE™

<br><br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Why are you doing form validation as soon as the DOM is ready?

Comment: I am not sure, because I am not too experienced javascript coder. I got the script online and did some modification. Maybe we should use click event instead?

Comment: I experimented a bit and I found out that if I comment out first function `document.addEventListener()` and now I get a generic prompt `Please fill out this field.`. Maybe I should just comment out first function and modify other two functions to achieve my goal? If I do this also now one click on the submit button does the job and form is sent while before I had to click submit twice.

Comment: Ok I solved the problem of showing the same messages by changing `var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");` to `var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("vnos");` but still **I have to click submit button twice**... Could anyone help me with that?

Comment: Maybee I get these problems because I mixed `document.addEventListener` with `onclick` parameter...

Comment: You have the problems because you set up event listeners twice...Once when the document is ready  and again with the `onclick`. All of this code is a mess, frankly. If you are going to rely on HTML validation, then you don't need to check the text boxes for input at all because you have the `required` attribute set up on each of them.

Comment: OK. I understand. But what If I want to set up a custom prompt message?

Comment: Then you do need to perform your own validation logic, but you would do this via the form's `submit` event and no where else (all those `onclick` attributes go away) and you call the `checkValidity()` method of your `form` object to initially determine if the form is valid or not. Then, if it's not, you can check the textboxes and call `setCustomValidity()` method as needed.

Comment: Additionally, your `form` element isn't even set up correctly. You don't use the `target` attribute on a `form` element, you set up the `method` and `action` attributes.

Comment: Ok thank you I got it working. I used ID's instead of names and I used onclick on Submit button.

Comment: That's incorrect. Form elements **must** have the name attribute specified for them if they are to submit their values. You may also add an `id` as well (which aids in CSS and JavaScript). Really, your code is a mess and even your basic HTML isn't valid. You need to go back and write proper HTML before you worry about JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you. I will check it.